# problem with linq to sqlite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, dblinq

I am using vb.net sqlite.net and dblinq0.20.1 to search a sqlite table on a primary key field.

My code looks like this

```
Dim blb = (From d In db.Data Where d.UID = myuid Select d).Single
```

This returns the error "Coalesce used with type that cannot be null"

If I search on a nullable field it works fine.

Anyone come across this error before and throw any light on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message was a bit misleading.  The field in question (the primary key for the table) was in fact nullable whereas it should not have been.  I changed the field property to 'not null' and the linq query worked as expected.